# How to show video on my post template?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress technology.I get post from my database and now i want to display video in my posts.Here is my code

```
<?php while(have_posts()):
      the_post();
?>
<?php the_content()?>
<?php endif;?>
```

But the videos are not showing in my posts.why?
I want to show it in using excert()

Comment: How you have uploaded the video using some plugin or through the Media Gallery Itself:)

Comment: Or you just use some embed code from YouTube or other source?

Answer (score 0):

> You can have a try like this.

Your theme may be using `<?php the_excerpt();?>` instead of `<?php the_content();?>` in its index.php template files. Try editing the index.php and replacing `<?php the_excerpt();?>` with `<?php the_content();?>`. **Or add your video to the option Excerpt field on each Post.**

```
<?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endif;?>
```